# Servlet - which is more efficient when providing a downloadable file?

Tags: java, servlets

I am currently writing a dropbox sort of servlet and am at the stage that I can provide downloadable files and I was wondering which if there is a difference in efficience between these following two methods.

This is the method I am using at the moment to provide a download, I am using a `FileInputStream` to write the file that is getting downloaded:

```
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");   
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + "/" + fileName + "\""); 
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath[1]);
            int i;   
            while ((i=fileInputStream.read()) != -1)
            {  
                out.write(i);   
            }   
            fileInputStream.close();   
            out.close();
```

But after doing some research I found out that the majority of people uses a `byte` kind of approach instead:

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(my_file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int length;
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
in.close();
out.flush();
```

Is my approach inferior in any way? or is the above method just more popular because it is less code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) is optimized to work with `CharSequence`:

> Prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream.
>
> Abstract class for writing to character streams. (from [`Writer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) documentation)

In you code you read from the file byte by byte and you copy that byte on the `PrintWriter`. It will be more efficient to read line by line and write a complete line to the `PrintWriter`.

---

Using directly the `OutputStream` you read and write chunk of 4096 bytes. This is more efficient in terms of cpu because you make less `while` loops.

In any case the difference is very limited because here the speed is not related to the cpu, but to the speed of the network. If you try to test the speed of both methods you will see that there is no measurable difference and that they can be strongly influenced from the network traffic.

Additionally the `PrintWriter` should be used only with text files, instead the `OutputStream` solution is not dependent from the type of file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils for this task

```
        try {
             // getting output and input streams 
             // Setting response headers.                 
               out.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
               out.flush();
        } catch(Exception e) {//or you can handle the appropriate Exception.
        } finally {
               IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        }
```

Comment: What if you're trying to send a 10GB file?  How well will that work with a 64MB JVM?

Comment: @stdunbar It will throw OOM . My code is just an example of the better way of copying stream to the response.  If it's 10GB file , you will get OOM anyway if you use 64MB JVM , unless you send the file in chunks.  I would rather prefer some other way , like cloud storage and file sharing services make sending large files easier than ever, and an often be much faster and more reliable.